# Android - Checking RTMP link

Tags: android, rtmp

I have developed an app which streams rtmp link. The problem is how can i check whether my rtmp link is active or not (of course without opening it)?

Comment: can you share the library you used?

Comment: You can use Vitamio or Exoplayer

Comment: can you share a code or tutorial?